# Is the behaviour of associative array keys in php 8.0.2 different to php 7? Should I enclose array keys in quotes, or not?

Tags: php, associative-array, php-7, php-8

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?
How do the double and single quotes affect the behaviour of the associative array keys?
Is this behaviour different to php 7, why?

```
      <?php
        // php version 8.0.2
        echo "$assoc_array[key]";   // OK
        echo  $assoc_array[key];    // error undefined constant "key"
        echo  $assoc_array['key'];  // OK
        echo "$assoc_array['key']"; // error - unexpected string content ""
        // this behaviour seems inconsistent
      ?>
```

Comment: Inside a quoted string, use `{}` with quoted array keys. `"{$assoc['key']}"` or do not use `{}` and do not quote the key (I strongly prefer quoted keys) `"$assoc[key]"`. Prior to PHP 8 an unquoted key outside a double quoted string like `$assoc[key]` worked with a warning, deprecated in 7.x. That is no longer allowed in 8 - you must always quote keys except inside the double quoted string.

Comment: On the [PHP 7.4 to 8 migration guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php): _"Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined. Previously, unqualified constant accesses resulted in a warning and were interpreted as strings._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at each line...

```
echo  $assoc_array[key];
```

Anything `string` that isn't preceded with certain characters (e.g. `$|->`), terminated with certain characters (e.g. `(`), or inside of quotes (or `heredoc` etc.) is assumed to be a constant.

Which means `key` is usually assumed to be a constant. But you haven't set a constant value for `key` and therefore PHP has to do something with it...

Before PHP 8.x that would mean assume it was supposed to be a string and try the look up again; this would generate a `warning`.

This behaviour changed in PHP 8.x and now it throws an `Error`. Which, if not handled, ends the script.

```
echo "$assoc_array[key]";
```

In this case `key` is enclosed in quotes and thus, treated as a string. Arguably I'd suggest that this should throw an error as well; it would seem more consistent.

However, it's the same behaviour across PHP 7 & 8.

```
echo  $assoc_array['key'];
```

This is just *the* standard way to access an associative array; single or double quotes would be fine. Again, this behaviour is consistent across PHP versions.

```
echo "$assoc_array['key']";
```

This one's a bit trickier. What it comes down to is that using double quotes and variables is a *tricky* business. PHP has to try and decide what parts are meant literally and what parts are identifiers and the current process is that quotes around keys is not allowed.

This is consistent across PHP versions.

---

Effectively PHP provides two ways of defining variables inside of double quotes:

**simple**

This means a variable preceded with a `$`. Which can be used like:

```
echo "$variable";
echo "$array[key]";
```

**Complex**

This means almost *any* variable you can think of in PHP. Which is used like:

```
echo "{$variable}";
echo "${variable}
echo "{$array['key']}";
echo "${array['key']}";
echo "{$array["key"]}";
echo "${array["key"]}";
echo "{$object->property}";
```

---

See the `PHP 7 >> 8` migration manual for further information on the backwards compatibility:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

**N.B.** The key difference, for your purposes, is that the way undefined constants is handled has changed (as above) from a `Warning` to an `Error Exception`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example, I used the following code to test:

```
<?php

$assoc_array = ['key' => 'okay'];

echo "$assoc_array[key]";   // OK
echo  $assoc_array[key];    // error undefined constant "key"
echo  $assoc_array['key'];  // OK
#echo "$assoc_array['key']"; // error - unexpected string content ""
```

Using PHP 7.2.34, I get the following results:

```
okayPHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/summea/example.php on line 6
okayokay
```

When I uncomment the last line from the above code, I get something like:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ...
```

---

Then, when running the above code in a [PHP 8.0.0 editor online](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), I get:

```
okay<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant &quot;key&quot; in [...][...]:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

So, it appears that this `PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant key` warning from PHP 7.2.34 was changed into an Error at least by PHP 8.0.0.

When I uncomment the last line in the above code and run in PHP 8.0.0, I get:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected string content &quot;&quot;, expecting &quot;-&quot; or identifier or variable or number in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

---

From these tests, I would recommend using the two general ideas below for this (for PHP 7.x.x and 8.0.0):

- When dealing with an array_name[key] (without outer quotes), it seems safe to use this format: `$array_name['key']`.
- When dealing with an "array_name[key]" (within outer quotes), it seems safe to use this format: `"{$array_name['key']}"`.

---

Hopefully in answer to part of your questions, the "undefined constant key" error appears to happen because of a change between PHP 7.2.34 and PHP 8.0.0.

The "unexpected string content" error happens because I think you need to have `{...}` braces around an array with a key with single quotes when inside an outer double-quoted string in order to make it work. This particular behavior seems to be similar in both PHP 7.2.34 and PHP 8.0.0.

If, for example, you were to try using outer single quotes instead of double quotes, like this:

```
echo '{$assoc_array["key"]}';
```

In PHP 7.2.34 and PHP 8.0.0, the result should be:

```
{$assoc_array["key"]}
```

which is not quite what you want (it appears to be printing a literal version of your string). Thus, I would still recommend using the `"{$array_name['key']}"` format.

Comment: Thanks, that helps to clarify things a little. I guess this means that if a system is updated to version 8, all the code has to be checked for compliance so that it will run without error. In my case it doesn't mean much but in enterprise level projects it would stymie the adoption of version 8 wouldn't it?

Comment: @ScottMerewetherRankin Glad to hear that! And as far as checking code between PHP 7.x.x and 8.x.x, checking code would probably be a good idea. I remember reading about how [challenging the move](https://24daysindecember.net/2020/12/21/a-perfect-storm/) to PHP 8 is for some people or projects. I would guess that moving to PHP 8 is going to be harder for some projects compared to moving between PHP 7.1 to 7.2 to 7.3, etc.

Comment: @ScottMerewetherRankin in short "no, it wouldn't". The _errors_ have always been there and **no one** should be producing production code with _warnings_ being generated (there's not really an excuse to have _notices_ either). The key difference in PHP 8 is that this warning (RE undefined constants) has been elevated to an `Error` exception...

Comment: @summea To clear up on your last point: single quotes (and `nowdoc`) have only ever been for literal string printing. Pretty much the only _special_ characters are `\'` and `\\` for a single quote and backslash respectively. If you want to use variables and other _special_ characters (e.g. `\n`) then you need to use double quotes (or `heredoc`); again, this has always been the case.

Comment: All helpful advice. Thank you.